# How to use dplyr to group_by multiple variables and sum other variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe `combined_data` that looks like this (this is just an example):

```
Year    state_name       VoS_thousUSD     industry
2008    Alabama          100              Shipping
2009    Alabama          100              Shipping
2008    Alabama          200              Shipping
2010    Alabama          100              Shipping
2010    Alabama          50               Shipping
2010    Alabama          100              Shipping
2008    Alabama          100              Shipping
```

There are multiple `Year`, `state_name`, and `industry`
variable, with associated `VoS_thousUSD` values, as well as other columns I no longer need.

I am trying to produce this

```
Year    state_name       VoS_thousUSD     industry
2008    Alabama          400              Shipping
2009    Alabama          100              Shipping
2010    Alabama          250              Shipping
```

Where the dataframe is grouped by `Year`, `state_name`, and `industry`, and `VoS_thousand` is a sum by those groups.

So far I have

```
combined_data %>%
  group_by(Year, state_name, GCAM_industry) %>% 
  summarise() -> VoS_thousUSD_state_ind
```

But I am not sure how/where to add in the sum for `VoS_thousUSD`. Would like to use a dplyr pipeline.

Comment: Change `summarise()` to `summarise(Vos_thousUSD = sum(Vos_thousUSD))`

Comment: I mean, I don't always dupe-close, but for the the top R-FAQs I pretty much always do when I see it. When my page reloaded after closing, your answer loaded with it. Isn't comment and close much more efficient than writing the same answer again and again?

Comment: @akrun and that one has a twist!

Comment: I'm sure I've missed many - sum by group, mean by group, sorting, merging, I'm sure the top FAQs have 1000s of unmarked dupes. But when I see it and am in it, I try to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
aggregate( VoS_thousUSD~ ., combined_data, FUN = sum)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
combined_data %>%
   group_by(Year, state_name, industry) %>% 
   summarise(VoS_thousUSD = sum(VoS_thousUSD))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Year, state_name [3]
#   Year state_name industry VoS_thousUSD
#  <int> <chr>      <chr>           <int>
#1  2008 Alabama    Shipping          400
#2  2009 Alabama    Shipping          100
#3  2010 Alabama    Shipping          250
```

#### data

```
combined_data <- structure(list(Year = c(2008L, 2009L, 2008L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2008L), state_name = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama"), VoS_thousUSD = c(100L, 100L, 
200L, 100L, 50L, 100L, 100L), industry = c("Shipping", "Shipping", 
"Shipping", "Shipping", "Shipping", "Shipping", "Shipping")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: I have been asked not to use the aggregate function, and to use a tidyverse pipeline instead. Still possible?

Comment: @MarideeWeber i added that